# Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of ""

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ruby-on-rails-7

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Failed to load Vuejs components

I use Ruby-on-Rails 7 for the backend part, and VueJS 3 for frontend.

I added vue js dependencies to importmap configuration.
Path: config/importmap.rb:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "vue", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vue@3.2.26/dist/vue.esm-browser.js"
```

path : app/javascript/application.js

```
import * as View from "view"
import PollShow from "./PollShow.vue"

const app = Vue.createApp()

app.component('PollShow', PollShow)
app.mount('#poll_show')
```

And then added vue js import vuejs and component PollShow.vue in application.js
However vue js import works well but component import is not working.
Do you have any idea why this is not working ?

Comment: the problem is with the server not sending any mime type - client code is irrelevant - so, nothing to do with javascript or vuejs if the server is broken

Comment: This one seems to work: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.26/vue.esm-browser.min.js